# Entity Framework Code First cascading relationship

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework-6

I am trying to create a code first approach using the Entity framework 6 and  SQL Ce database.  When I create a game with a home and away team and also a season, the team is updated with the game, but the Season is not.

A Season consists of many Teams and many games.

A Team plays many games is also present in many leagues seasons.

A Game is part of a leagues season and has a home team and an away team.

```
 public class Season {
      public int ID { get; private set; }
      public ICollection<Team> Teams;
      public ICollection<Game> Games;
 }
public class Team {
        public int ID { get; private set; }
        public string Name {get;set;}
        public ICollection<Game> Games;
        public ICollection<Season> Seasons;
 }
 public class Game {
      public int ID { get; private set; }
      public Season Season;
      public Team HomeTeam;
      public Team AwayTeam;
 }

public class SeasonConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Season> {
    public SeasonConfiguration() {
        HasKey(s => s.ID);
        HasMany(g => g.Games).WithOptional(s => s.Season);

        //I've read that this should work for a many-to-many relationship, but it doesn't seem to work here!
        HasMany(t => t.Teams).WithMany(p => p.Seasons).Map(x =>
        {
            x.MapLeftKey("TeamID");
            x.MapRightKey("SeasonID");
            x.ToTable("SeasonTeams");
        });
    }

public class TeamConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Team> {
    public TeamConfiguration() {
        HasKey(t => t.ID);
        HasMany(g => g.Games).WithOptional(t => t.AwayTeam).Map(m => m.MapKey("AwayTeamID"));
        HasMany(g => g.Games).WithOptional(t => t.HomeTeam).Map(m => m.MapKey("HomeTeamID"));
 }

 public class GameConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Game> {
      public GameConfiguration() {
        HasKey(a => a.ID);
        HasOptional(s => s.Season).WithMany(g => g.Games).Map(m => m.MapKey("SeasonID"));            

        HasOptional(t => t.HomeTeam).WithMany().Map(m => m.MapKey("HomeTeamID"));
        HasOptional(t => t.AwayTeam).WithMany().Map(m => m.MapKey("AwayTeamID"));
      }
 }
```

When the application is run and the database is created with seed values, it creates a SeasonTeams table with SeasonID and TeamID.

When a game is added, which includes team and season, while the team is updated with the game, the SeasonTeams table is not updated and as a result, when I try to get all teams from a season, nothing is returned. ie.

The following code is typically how I'd use the above, however, no results are given.

```
 Season season2016 = new Season("2016");
 Game game = new Game {HomeTeam= "Leicester City", AwayTeam="Arsenal", Season=season2016};
 context.SaveChanges();

 Season season = GetSeason();
 foreach(Team team in season.Teams) {
      Console.WriteLine(team.Name);
 }
```

Other queries of Season.Games, Team.Games & Team.Season work as expected.

I am new to code first development with the entity framework, so am fumbling around a lot at the moment and some of the above code, is probably not optimal.  Any suggestions for improvement in addition to assistance with my issue are welcome.

Ideally, I would like the season to be updated when I add a game with a reference to the season but do not know how to achieve this, please assist.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I have just read that many-to-many relationships are not supported with EF.  I suspect that this is why my code doesn't work.

Comment: I have kind of solved this, by adding a check in the Game.Season Set property and in the Game.HomeTeam & Game.AwayTeam Set properties to check if the team exists in the Season.Teams collection and add it, if it doesn't.  I'm not convinced this is a very elegant solution though.

Comment: Many to many relationship is possible in EF code first =>
modelBuilder.Entity<Pocos.Customer>()
                .HasMany<Contact>(s => s.Contacts)
                .WithMany(c => c.Customers)
                .Map(cs =>
                {
                    cs.MapLeftKey("CustomerId");
                    cs.MapRightKey("ContactId");
                    cs.ToTable("CustomersContacts");
                });

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used your model and persist it to a local DB.

[image]

Everything is fine here (the 'SeasonTeams' table is not visible due to the many to many relationship)

From your scenario I understand you are doing something similar to this:

```
using (var sportContext = new Sport())
{
    var season2016 = sportContext.Seasons.First();

    var homeTeam = sportContext.Teams.Where(w => w.Name == "Leicester City").First();
    var awayTeam = sportContext.Teams.Where(w => w.Name == "Arsenal").First();

    Game game = new Game { HomeTeam = homeTeam , AwayTeam = awayTeam, Season = season2016 };

    //Populate the SeasonTeams Table
    var teamList = season2016.Teams.ToList();
    teamList.Add(homeTeam);
    teamList.Add(awayTeam);

    season2016.Teams = (teamList);

    sportContext.Games.Add(game);
    sportContext.SaveChanges();

    var season = sportContext.Seasons.First();

    var seasons = sportContext.Entry(season).Collection(c => c.Teams).Query();

    foreach (Team team in seasons)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(team.Name);
    }
}
```

Note that using this will automaticaly add the new created Team to the Teams table and to the SeasonTeams table